# Basic question on merging functions from different dimensions ($g(f) = g \circ f, f = \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, g = \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$)

Tags: functions

Is it possible to merge 2 functions in that order: $g(f) = g \circ f$ when:

- $f(x_1 ; x_2) = -8x_1 + 3x_2$ [$\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$]
- $g(x_1 ; x_2 ; x_3 ; x_4) = (x_1 + x_2 - x_3 - x_4 \ ; \ -2x_1 + 5x_3 - 7x_4)$ [$\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$]

Will the answer be:

$$g(f) = g \circ f = g(-8x_1 + 3x_2) = (-8x_1 + 3x_2 \ ; \ -2(-8x_1 + 3x_2))$$

I in my assumption, while operating on g, I treat everyting as $x_1$ and make $x_2 = 0 , x_3 =0, x_4 =0$
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this makes no sense. You can do $f\circ g$, but not $g\circ f$. $f(x)\in\Bbb R$ and $g$ needs an input from $\Bbb R^4$, right?

Comment: great, thanks, q closed

Comment: You're not supposed to close questions as soon as they're answered. Just accept the answer and move on.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that I don't need anybody more to help me, I can accept it in 10mins. And that is what I will do. I mean that by "question closed.

Comment: Gotcha. No problem. :)